Having Address format, infer derivation path or BIP used
Hello fellow Bitcoiners.
While studing bitcoin, I came across an issue, I wanted to ask if someone knows how to know which derivation path a 1xxxxxxxxxxx address was created with.
I know that bc1xxxxxxxxxx addresses uses BIP84
3xxxxxxxx addresses uses BIP49
but 1xxxxxxxx addresses could have use BIP32 or BIP44.
Is there a way to know which method (BIP32 or BIP44) was used by only having the address ? My guess is not, but wanted to ask anyways.
Thanks in advanced

Does this answer your question? Most common derivation Paths, accounts and indexes

Thanks for the link. I just want to know if is possible to tell BIP32 & BIP44 apart. But as I suspected. There is none

No, you cannot.
One issue is as you pointed out that some address types have multiple standard derivation paths/methods associated with them, and the data encoded inside the address is indistinguishable from random (apart from the version number/type of address used).
But even beyond that, nobody is required to follow such standards. Many wallets have their own conventions.

Thank you very much for the explanation Pieter.
